# How to pass notification content text to EditText in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to fill EditText automatically after notification clicked. This EditText filled by value of notification content text. As a notification service I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging

[Here what my app look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYSN7.jpg)

And this is the code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    mCurrent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCurrent);
    mDestiny = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDestination);
    mFind = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCari);

    String string1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("string1");
    mCurrent.setText(string1);

    mFind.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendRequest();
        }
    });

}
```

[sample send message from FCM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCwAP.png)

Comment: add the code that you use to send notification thanks

Comment: i am not write any code to send notification, my app just receive notification. To send a notification i am using Firebase Cloud Notification from https://console.firebase.google.com

Answer (score 1):

So you can **try this** inside activity:

```
    String string1=getIntent().getStringExtra("str1");
    String string2=getIntent().getStringExtra("str2");
    String string3=getIntent().getStringExtra("str3");
    String string4=getIntent().getStringExtra("str4");
    String string5=getIntent().getStringExtra("str5");
```

And do this in **console**:

1)In notifications go to the advanced options;

2)In key textfield set str1 and in value textfield set value.Do it in the above textfild for exemple:

**Key**: str1 **value**: somevalue

**key**: str2 **value**: somevalue

**key**: str3 **value**: somevalue

**key**: str4 **value**: somevalue

**key**: str5 **value**: somevalue

3)Send notification and see if Works.

Here is an image to better help:

[image: image of options]

Comment: how can i pass these value to EditText ?

Comment: get values as i said using String string1=getIntent().getStringExtra("str1");
 and to set edittext do this edittext.setText(string1);

Comment: I've done everything, but it didnt work. I've updated my question to make it more clear

Comment: @EgeekC try this: String string1= getIntent().getExtras().get("str1").toString();

Comment: There is no error in the program code, there is only a warning `Method invocation 'toString' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException' `. But the app is stopped working

Comment: what is the logcat? To avoid the warning do this: if(getIntent() !=null){ String string1= getIntent().getExtras().get("str1").toString(); } @EgeekC

Comment: logcat showing error `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{class}: java.lang.NullPointerException`